# Magnetic field in the cavity of a conducting cylindrical wire

Tags: magnetic-fields

Assuming that you have a infinite long conducting cylindrical wire: Is it possible to let the magnetic field be constant inside the cavity and why?

Comment: To me, this reads like a homework type question, so I think you should give your own thoughts and references in your post.  Something like this http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elecyl.html

Comment: Where is the return current going ?

Comment: If we assume infinitely long conducting pipe will there be any role for the return current?

Comment: This is an interesting question, hope I understood it the right way. Do you found an answer by yourself?

Comment: Does your problem have any practical relevance?